# Extraction mechanism of Coq generate "failwith "AXIOM TO BE REALIZE""

Tags: ocaml, coq, coq-extraction

I have a module structure inside this module I declare a variable use for some function inside `module A`.

```
Module A.

  Variable a : nat.   

End A.
```

Then I use extraction mechanism.

```
Extraction Language Ocaml.   
Set Extraction Optimize.
Set Extraction AccessOpaque.
Extraction A.
```

or just

```
Extraction A.
```

It generated for me the code with a warning:
"The following axiom must be realized in the extracted code: A.a"

```
type nat =
| O
| S of nat

module A = 
 struct 
  (** val a : nat **)

  let a =
    failwith "AXIOM TO BE REALIZED"
 end
```

Here I received `a` with the `failwith "AXIOM TO BE REALIZED"`
I couldn't run my function success because of this `failwith`

Because I have to use the variable `a` inside the module. 
I want to know is there a way to define a module that it won't generate `failwith` after the extraction? or something to do with the extraction that will not generate this `failwith` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, at some point you'll have to provide a value for `A.a`. If you want to abstract `A` with respect to `a`, I guess that the most convenient way is to use a functor, which is directly translated as such in OCaml:

```
Module Type Param.
  Variable x: nat.
End Param.

Module A (Import P: Param).

  Definition a:=P.x.   

End A.

Extraction Language Ocaml.   
Set Extraction Optimize.
Set Extraction AccessOpaque.

Extraction "test.ml" A.
```

(Of course, you must instantiate the resulting OCaml functor `A` to run a computation).